# Regular Expression for mailto link

Tags: c#, regex, mailto

We have a library which outputs the following string (we can't change the library to output what we want):

```
<p>Please contact <a href="mailto:here&amp;there@me.com">here&amp;there@me.com</a></p>
```

This html doesn't work, as clicking on the link opens and email addressed simpley to "here".

I would like to convert this to, for example:

```
<p>Please contact <a href="mailto:here%26there@me.com">here&amp;there@me.com</a></p>
```

Which does work properly when clicked on.

Note that this string could contain multiple email addresses.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?  We are using C#.

Comment: how is the email address being populated? what's the code that pulls the email address from "the library" and places it on the page?

Comment: I'm getting this string from the database. I have no control over how it is populated.

Comment: Without knowing what part of this string is constant, what part is variable (that could  be any thing), it's a waste of time to try to write a regex for it.

Comment: Generally, the simpler the better,  Find: `(mailto:.*?)&amp;`, replace: `$1%26` should work.

Comment: Thanks sln - that replace works great.

Answer (score 0):

In C# this is easy, use a string replace function:

```
string s = "I am a scary fox";
string v = s.Replace("scary", "not scary");
```

Replace will change any found substring that matches, so you don't need to use for while loops etc, it's easy.

For substring in a string use `instr` (but that's VB talk), so in C# you use `indexof`.

Comment: If you look at my question, you'll see that I don't want to replace all instances of &amp; in the string.

Comment: Then first create a substring from your main string where you want to change things, could be done easily some mid and instr function to locate the " ...still easy and no need for regex

Comment: wrongly wrote instr, in c# its indexof, my advice spend some time in string functions, as lots of it is used in normal programming.